# How to do random message?

Tags: discord.js

I have tried this code

```
const botId = "96310595965*****48";

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    if (message.mentions.has(botId)) { 
        message.reply(randomMessage);
    };
});

setInterval(async function(){
const messages = [ "Yes" , "No" , "Idk" ]; 
const randomMessage = messages [Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
console.log(randomMessage)
}, 700)
```

But when I ping the bot it crashed.
This show in console:

```
message.reply(randomMessage);
              ^
```

Can someone help me? Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this but the reason for the error was that you were calling the const `randomMessage` before it was defined (randomMessage should be above where it is needed but a function for it isn't needed.)

```js
const botId = "96310595965*****48";

client.on("message", async message => {
    const messages = [ "Yes" , "No" , "Idk" ]; 
    const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.mentions.has(botId)) { 
        message.reply(randomMessage);
    };
});

// Code below not needed
// setInterval(async function(){
// const messages = [ "Yes" , "No" , "Idk" ]; 
// const randomMessage = messages [Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
// console.log(randomMessage)
// }, 700)
```

Side note if using Discord v13 rather than v12 use the below code rather than the above code

```js
const botId = "96310595965*****48";

client.on("messageCreate", async message => {
    const messages = [ "Yes" , "No" , "Idk" ]; 
    const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.mentions.has(botId)) { 
        message.reply(randomMessage);
    };
});

// Code below not needed
// setInterval(async function(){
// const messages = [ "Yes" , "No" , "Idk" ]; 
// const randomMessage = messages [Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
// console.log(randomMessage)
// }, 700)
```