# Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length); not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
const replies = [
    "image 1",
    "image 2",
    "image 3",
    "image 4",
    "image 5"
];

const reply = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length);
const words = replies[reply]
   message.channel.send(words);
```

So i have this simple discord bot code which i supposed to reply with a random message from replies list, the bot works and everything but keep outputting the same message over and over instead of a random one (image 5)

Comment: Are you recalculating `Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)` for each reply? I have the feeling that you generate a random index once, then proceed to re-use the same random index for each reply.

Comment: try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845230/how-to-do-random-message/71845403#71845403

Comment: I havent thought about that, how could i recalculate it?

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845230/how-to-do-random-message/71845403#71845403

Comment: alrighty the link @Hadtaw sent worked for me thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your code works!

```js
const replies = [
    "image 1",
    "image 2",
    "image 3",
    "image 4",
    "image 5"
];

const reply = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length);
const words = replies[reply]
console.log(words)
```

If you just console out `words` variable this appears to work how you want it to. You can see in the snippet that each time you run the code, a random image is returned.

As @3limin4to0r mentioned, this may be an issue with reusing the same index if you are running this multiple times.